# How to get onclick to work multiple times

Tags: javascript

sorry if this is a stupidly simple question I'm very new to all this. Im making a very basic Rock Paper Scissors game. I wanted to make a button to clear the results on the page to uncluttered it a bit. However my reset button only works on the first click. I'm not too sure what's going wrong here. I'm sure its a simple solution im just very inexperienced.

```
const player = {
 currentChoice: null
}
const computer= {
  currentChoice: null
}
const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

function computerChooses(){
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
  computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
  displayResult("The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice);
}
function playerChooses(){
  const lapis = document.getElementById("Lapis");
  lapis.onclick = function a(){player.currentChoice = choices[0];
   displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
computerChooses();
compareChoices();
                              
   }
 
  const papyrus = document.getElementById("Papyrus");
  papyrus.onclick = function b(){
    player.currentChoice = choices[1];
    displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    computerChooses();
  compareChoices();
  }
  
  const scalpellus = document.getElementById("Scalpellus");
  scalpellus.onclick = function c(){
    player.currentChoice = choices[2];
    displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    computerChooses();
    compareChoices();
    
    
  }
 
  
}

function resetText(){
 const resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");
  resetButton.onclick = function d(){
    document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = " ";
    
  }

}
function compareChoices(){
  if(computer.currentChoice ===   player.currentChoice){
   displayResult("It's a tie you both chose " + computer.currentChoice);
  }else if(computer.currentChoice === choices[0]){
    if(player.currentChoice === choices[1]){
      displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
    }else{
      displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }
}else if(computer.currentChoice === choices[1]){
  if(player.currentChoice === choices[2]){
    displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }else{
    displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice)
  }
}else if(computer.currentChoice === choices[2]){
  if(player.currentChoice === choices[0]){
    displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }else{
    displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
  }
}
  
}
function displayResult(result){
  const resultText = document.createElement("p");
  resultText.innerText = result;
  document.body.appendChild(resultText);
  const resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");
  resetButton.onclick = function f (){
    resultText.innerText = null;
    ;
  }
}

playerChooses();
resetText();
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be better if you also linked your HTML for your question, but it looks like each time you call `displayResult()`, you create a new paragraph tag (`p`) that gets appended to the body. In the function `resetText()`, you retrieve the first instance of the `p` tag with `document.querySelector("p")`, which doesn't account for the newly created elements (if that makes sense).

The best fix to this would be to use `document.querySelector("p")` in replace of the `document.createElement("p")`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did some adjustments to your code and for me seems to work:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
   const player = {
       currentChoice: null
   }
   const computer = {
       currentChoice: null
   }
   const choices = ["Lapis", "Papyrus", "Scalpellus"];

   function computerChooses() {
       const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
       computer.currentChoice = choices[randomIndex];
       displayResult("The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice);
   }

   function playerChooses() {
       const lapis = document.getElementById("Lapis");
       lapis.onclick = function a() {
           player.currentChoice = choices[0];
           displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           computerChooses();
           compareChoices();
           
       }
       
       const papyrus = document.getElementById("Papyrus");
       papyrus.onclick = function b() {
           player.currentChoice = choices[1];
           displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           computerChooses();
           compareChoices();
       }
       
       const scalpellus = document.getElementById("Scalpellus");
       scalpellus.onclick = function c() {
           player.currentChoice = choices[2];
           displayResult("The player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           computerChooses();
           compareChoices();
       }
   }

   function resetText() {
       const resetButton = document.getElementById("resetButton");
       resetButton.onclick = function d() {
            console.log("clicked");
            Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p")).forEach(
              function(item) {
                item.remove();
                // or item.parentNode.removeChild(item); for older browsers (Edge-)
            });
       }
   }

   function compareChoices() {
       if (computer.currentChoice === player.currentChoice) {
           displayResult("It's a tie you both chose " + computer.currentChoice);
       } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
           if (player.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
               displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           } else {
               displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           }
       } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[1]) {
           if (player.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
               displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           } else {
               displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice)
           }
       } else if (computer.currentChoice === choices[2]) {
           if (player.currentChoice === choices[0]) {
               displayResult("The player wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           } else {
               displayResult("The computer wins! The computer chose " + computer.currentChoice + " and the player chose " + player.currentChoice);
           }
       }
       
   }

   function displayResult(result) {
       const resultText = document.createElement("p");
       resultText.innerText = result;
       document.body.appendChild(resultText);
   }

   playerChooses();
   resetText(); 
});
```

The issue is you are only removing the text of the element, but the element itself is still into the DOM, and whenever you click on reset you rely only on the first element.

My suggestion would be create a div and put all results into that div, then you just erase the content from the div.

Also you dont need to create again into displayResult the same function that you have, the trick here is to loop over all

elements that you created and delete them.

But this can be easily done without this loop if you put everything into a div as I wrote before.

Comment: Suggest to highlight the change you made on the code to make it more friendly on reading

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).